# Output XML with single quotes instead of double for attribute values

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have this XML document, and I need to replace the dobule quotation marks with single quotes (the apostrophe):

```
<det nItem="1">
<prod>
    <cProd>0320</cProd>
<prod>  
</det>
<det nItem="2">
<prod>
    <cProd>0320</cProd>
<prod>  
</det>
```

I want it to be.

```
<det nItem='1'>
<prod>
    <cProd>0320</cProd>
<prod>  
</det>
<det nItem='2'>
<prod>
    <cProd>0320</cProd>
<prod>  
</det>
```

I have tried using ElementTree but it can't be configured to use a different quoting style.

Comment: Since both styles are legal in XML, why do you need to force single quotes?

Comment: Because the API server i'm using to send this XML, is having problems reading files with quotation marks.

Comment: Oh dear. That's... irritating.

Comment: I suspect you've misdiagnosed the problem. I find it highly unlikely that any XML-reading application would insist on single quotes rather than double quotes. (Actually no. I've been on SO long enough that I should know that incompetence knows no limits. But I wouldn't trust such an application with my data.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse the lines in the file to a new file, replacing the characters as you go.  This swaps single quotes for `&apos;`, and then double quotes for single.

```
with open('file1.xml') as fp_in:
    with open('file2.xml') as fp_out:
        for line in fp_in:
            fp_out.write(line.replace("'", '&apos;').replace('"', "'"))
```

Comment: If the input file was generated by ElementTree, then this is indeed sufficient, as any character data *and* attribute values all have double quote characters escaped by ElementTree. For other XML files, you may want to parse-and-write with ET first.

Comment: Good to know thanks @MartijnPieters It is a little frustrating though